# Should I use HTTP search

Tags: api-design, http

I am working on a web api and I am curios about the `HTTP SEARCH` verb and how you should use it.

My first approach was, well you could use it surely for a search. But asp.net WebApi doesn't support the `SEARCH` verb.

My question is basically, should I use `SEARCH` or is it not important?

PS: I found the `SEARCH` verb in fiddler2 from telerik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP protocol is defined by RFC documents.  RFC2616 defines HTTP/1.1 the current release.

SEARCH is not documented as a verb in this document.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the `SEARCH` method is only a proposal and should not be used. Use `GET` instead.

Comment: At the moment I am using `GET`, but I like the idea to bring for every common situation a verb.

Comment: @Knerd The problem is that most HTTP clients will not support the `SEARCH` method which kind of defeats the motivation of providing an API.

Comment: You are right. Hopefully it becomes a part of HTTP :)